# Get HTML table data form specific website

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, socket.io, laravel-echo

All Sir,

I would like to know how and how to do show live data from thailand stock market website html data table.

thailand website = `https://marketdata.set.or.th/mkt/marketsummary.do?language=en&country=US`

and than i would like to show this data to our website.

simple website = myanmar123[dot]com

I want to create website like sample website.

what language i need to use and any suggestion and tutorial.

sample website use vue.js, laravel echo, socket.io, and bootstrap

when i search data from online i found `http://download.tentube.website/twod.php`

please help to create website like mynmar123[dot]com

and if not ok i want to create website like  `http://download.tentube.website/twod.php`

thank for helping and sorry for my bad english

Comment: It's a very general question. Please take a look here :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask